# Celery/Flask Receiving unregistered task of type (App Factory + Blueprints)

Tags: python, flask, celery

Using a Flask App factory set up in combination with Blueprints and Flask Restful api's causes issues with Celery 3.1.24 (im on windows).

Placing your `@celery.task` decorator inside of Flask-Restful's resource classes causes Celery to not detect any tasks when you try to run celery + redis so it can accept jobs.

Example of api_resource.py

````
   class Api(Resource)

    def patch(self, received_key):
       ```do work here```


        #start celery and task
        """ @celery.task(name='api.internal.upvote_task')
        def the_task(username, package, key_type, url):

            ExampleClass.launch_tasks(buyer_username= username, package = package, key_type= key_type, url = url) """

        the_task.apply_async(args=[username, package, key_type, url], countdown=10)
        return used_key, 202
````

i even tried adding a worker name `@celery.task(name='api.internal.the_task')`

I tried running it with

```
celery -A app worker -l info


celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=info


celery -A app.api.internal worker --loglevel=DEBUG
```

which was me trying to use direct paths to the tasks modules and trying to get celery to detect them itself.

I couldnt get celery to detect my task when it worked before i refactored my app and switched over to the app factory format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I finally figured out how to fix the issue wasnt by trying the 15 different ways to force celery to detect your tasks by absolute paths, putting it in python paths or anything.

Im actually a bit frustrated since   after a few hours of testing I finally moved my @celery.task function outside of my Resource class and just called it from within the class(in my case the api endpoint).

Celery picked it up, I tried it two different ways that worked after I made the change. The [first](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/celery-and-the-flask-application-factory-pattern/page/2#comments) is to set up a run.py/manage.py/celery_runnger.py like was shown in that tutorial. I tried it earlier and it didnt work from inside the class.

My only problem with that was I didnt want to push app context from there nor did I want to import celery in that file.

The second way was simply using an include in the celery config 
`celery = Celery(__name__, broker=Config.CELERY_BROKER_URL, include=['app.api.internal'])`

This too didnt previously work. Might seem obvious to some but using celery with all these different packages can be tricky and I hope this helps someone.

I still have to fix the issue of Flask SQLA not decting the flask app context when the task is run from celery but thats a different issue.